# Childhood dangers card game made in the 70s/80s

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone remember the name of a card game that was made in the 70s or 80s in which you collect cards in a sequence of events that was meant to teach kids to avoid household injuries?

Some of the card collections included: don't reach for a pot of boiling water, don't play with matches, and don't leave a rake in the grass with the tines sticking up. They had circles in the corner with symbols tied to the cards you were collecting (pot of water, match, etc.). The back of the cards might have had red crosses on them, but not sure.

My mom was a teacher, and says she may have bought them at an educational store in the Tacoma, WA area where I grew up. My sister and I joke that this game was a shared fever dream, since they were so weird (and morbid....the final cards all had children with x-out eyes), and no one else on earth seems to remember this game—Help!

Comment: This is probably not what you are looking for, unless yours is an older edition. Does «Cheers and Tears» sound right? https://www.wopc.co.uk/waddingtons/cheers-and-tears

Comment: Nope- but I really appreciate you trying to help :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like "Safety Quartett" (One of the thousands of Quartett / Go Fish! thematic decks).

Example card: https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1538979/quartett

And the one  with the rake: https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1538975/quartett

[image]

Comment: This might be it-thanks for pointing me in this direction!